# sqlalchemy no such table: user

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I've setup a flask site and I'm trying to get a signup page to work. The page itself renders but when I enter information in the form and submit I get a `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError`. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is my signup function:

```py
@auth.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup_post():
    email = request.form.get('email')
    name = request.form.get('name')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()  # if this returns a user,
    # then the email already exists in database

    if user:  # if a user is found, we want to redirect back to signup page so user can try again
        flash('email address already exists')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.signup'))

    # create a new user with the form data. Hash the password so the plaintext version isn't saved.
    new_user = user(email=email, name=name, password=generate_password_hash(password, method='sha256'))

    # add the new user to the database
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
```

The specific error says `no such table: user` then:

```
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.email AS user_email, user.password AS user_password, user.name AS user_name 
FROM user 
WHERE user.email = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: ('', 1, 0)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Here is where I initialize the DB and create the app:

```py
db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'UMGC-SDEV300-Key'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'

    db.init_app(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    from .models import User

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))

    # blueprint for auth routes in our app
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    # blueprint for non-auth parts of app
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

Comment: Looking at what the error says that you have posted it comes from `user = User.query.filter_by` line. Have you run the `db.create_all()` or do you have any system in place for SQLAlchemy migrations?

Answer (score 1):

Check the models.py and add the line: **tablename** = 'user'

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)  # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(30))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(30))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), uni
```

And in the **init**.py change to

```
@login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
```

And make sure that file exits,and have the table: user

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
```

Comment: Same problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I just needed to create the database. I went through this step once when I first created the application but I guess I missed something. I deleted the database and created a new one using the below command and that did the trick.

```py
from project import db, create_app
db.create_all(app=create_app())
```

This was done from the Python REPL.